# Get two values from the same column in the same query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization

I want to know how to get 2 different values from the same column in the same row. I mean, I have my table friends as shown below.

```
id | source | target
1    1        2
1    1        3
```

And then I have my users table, with the following values

```
id | name
1    John
2    Will
3    Mark
```

I want to know which users are friends, for example, in the first case it would be John and Will are friends.

Comment: According to your example, John and Will are friends, and so are John and Mark. So what makes the first one special? This is a basic JOIN query it looks like. You need to show an attempt at solving this before asking for help.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT in your SQL query

Comment: @saadzer What does that have to do with the question?

Comment: put some code you tried if you want the real help , we don't do here homewroks for people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might be looking for is a double join of the same lookup into a single driver:

```
SELECT
  src.name AS srcName,
  tgt.name AS targetName,
FROM
  friends
  INNER JOIN users AS src ON friends.source=src.id
  INNER JOIN users AS tgt ON friends.target=tgt.id
-- WHERE something?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following sql query

```
select u1.name,u2.name FROM friends as f
join users as u1 on f.source=u1.id
join users as u2 on f.Target=u2.id
```